# React: How to pass a function ("interpolations") to a styled component's template

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to build a bar graph using react. I'm using props to try to  pass a function ("interpolations") to a styled component's template in styled component but its showing an error message:

my styled-component:

```
export const Bar = styled.div`
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #64b2d1;
  width: ${props => props.width};
  animation-name: ${showBarOne};
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
`;
```

my component:

```
const Volume = ({widthBar}) =>{

  return(
     <VolumeContainer>
       
        <ProgressContainer>
          <Bar width='{widthBar}' ></Bar>
        </ProgressContainer>
     </VolumeContainer>
   )
  }
```

its showing a error inside the Volume component on the width variable.

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | ... 252 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
> Type '{ width: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & Partial<...>, "slot" | ... 254 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.

Comment: You are literally passing the string `{widthBar}` - surely you wanted `width={widthBar}`?

Comment: yes, because {widthBar} is my prop variable in Volume conponent and width is the variable i 'm passing to styled-component Bar as prop.width

Comment: You're doing this: `width: ${props => '{widthBar}'};` - the prop `width` is the string `{widthBar}`.

Comment: if a remove width  width and just use  {widthBar}  gives an error on prop.widthBar:

Comment: The error: Property 'widthBar' does not exist on type 'ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, any>'.ts(2339)

Comment: `<Bar width={widthBar}></Bar>` and `width: ${props => props.width};`